# How to express this `map` function using a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I have the following code

```
enum AppSubscription<Event>: Subscription {
    func map<ParentSubscription>(_ lift: @escaping (Event) -> (ParentSubscription.Event)) -> ParentSubscription where ParentSubscription: Subscription {
        switch self {
        case let .loadedArticles(cb):
            return AppSubscription<ParentSubscription.Event>.loadedArticles { article, isHot in lift(cb(article, isHot)) } as! ParentSubscription

        case let .savedArticles(cb):
            return AppSubscription<ParentSubscription.Event>.savedArticles { article in lift(cb(article)) } as! ParentSubscription

        case let .deletedArticles(cb):
            return AppSubscription<ParentSubscription.Event>.deletedArticles { article in lift(cb(article)) } as! ParentSubscription
        }
    }

    case loadedArticles((Article, Bool) -> Event)
    case savedArticles((Article) -> Event)
    case deletedArticles((Article) -> Event)
}
```

and I want to create a protocol for `Subscription` (that `AppSubscription` conforms to). This is my attempt so far

```
public protocol Subscription {
    associatedtype Event
    func map<ParentSubscription>(_ lift:
        @escaping (Event) -> (ParentSubscription.Event)) -> ParentSubscription where
        ParentSubscription: Subscription
}
```

but I get the errors

```
Subs.playground:21:31: Protocol 'Subscription' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

and

```
Subs.playground:21:28: Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'ParentSubscription' non-generic
```

How do I write the protocol's `map` function to match the implementation in `AppSubscription`?

---

**Edit**: Switched to `ParentSubscription: Subscription` as per @Fabian's suggestion. Also added missing `@escaping` to AppSubscription.

With the changes I'm not sure how to reconcile the protocol with the implementation. If I use the signature exactly as written in the protocol

```
func map<ParentSubscription, ParentEvent>(_ lift: @escaping (Event) -> (ParentEvent)) -> ParentSubscription where ParentSubscription : Subscription, ParentEvent == ParentSubscription.Event {
```

then I'm forced to use `as! ParentSubscription` which seems redundant. If I use the signature

```
func map<ParentEvent>(_ lift: (Event) -> ParentEvent) -> AppSubscription<ParentEvent> {
```

then it complains that the `AppSubscription` does not conform to the protocol. Is the only way to get it to compile to use `as!` ?

---

**Edit2**: Removed redundant `ParentEvent` and replaced with `ParentSubscription.Event` as per another suggestion by @Fabian.

The code now compiles which is great and many thanks to @Fabian.

I do think it's fair to say that the amount of type hinting seems awkward, is there any way to avoid or abbreviate any of it?

---

**Edit3**: Adding a repl link https://repl.it/@opsb/ScratchyTrustworthyArchitect to make it easy to play with.

Comment: Since `Subscription` protocal has an `associatedtype`, you must define `ParentSubscription: Subscription` instead of `ParentSubscription == Subscription`, so it has to be a type conforming that protocol.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated per your suggestion

Comment: In your `map` definition in the protocol, do you really need `ParentEvent`? Since you define `ParentSubscription.Event == ParentEvent` you could just use `ParentSubscription.Event` instead of `ParentEvent`

Comment: Another good suggestion, thanks, I've updated again